# How to find the mean of an occurrence in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
a = [[1.], [-1.], [1.]]
```

I have the above list. I want to find the value: (# of -1)/length of a. For the above example, the value is 1/3.

If we have

```
a = [[1.], [-1.], [1.], [-1.]]
```

then the value is 1/2.

How can I perform the above calculation in Python?

I've tried `a.count(-1)/a.shape[0]`, but that did not seem to work for list objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
a = [[1.], [-1.], [1.], [-1.]]
len([x[0] for x in a if x[0]==-1])/len(a)
```

Output

```
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: first, your list contains list. Doing `a.count(-1)` is searching the list for the integer `-1`. Instead, you have to search your list for the list containing `-1.` like so: `a.count([-1.])`.

Second, if you are just using a regular list then it does not have a `shape` property. That is for ndarrays. Instead just use `len(a)`.

So instead of using `a.count(-1)/a.shape[0]` you should use `a.count([-1.])/len(a)`.

**Edit: When a is an ndarray**

This can be done quite easily in the case where a is in fact an ndarray, but will look different from the case where a is just a python list. In a simple case of a list of lists containing a single real number each, the solution by Andy L. works fine.

However, recall that ndarrays are basically matrices and checking equality as suggested by Andy L. (`a == -1`) will check element-wise equality over the entire matrix. The downside to this arises when you want to check the number of rows in an ndarray matching a given row of some length greater than 1 (note that the solution I suggested above will still work if you want to check the number of lists in a python list matching a given list of arbitrary length).

An example:

Suppose we have an array

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [1, 2]
])
```

And we want to find the proportion of rows equal to `[1, 2]` (in this case .5). The solution proposed by Andy L. will not quite work in this case because if we try `a == [1, 2]` we will get the element-wise truth array:

```
[[True, True],
[False, True],
[True, False],
[True, True]]
```

Calling `.mean()` on this array will give us 6/8 = 0.75, not what we want. So we must add an extra step:

```
temp = (a == [1, 2]).all(axis=1)
proportion = np.sum(temp) / temp.shape[0]
```

Calling `.all(axis=1)` will reduce the array to a 1-dimensional array where each value is `True` if the corresponding row in `a == [1, 2]` was `[True, True]` and false otherwise. This will give us the desired result for checking row equality for rows of arbitrary length.

Comment: Thank you. I used `type(a)` and it says that `a` is a numpy.ndarray. So using `a.count([-1.])/len(a)` gives me the error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'. How can I fix this?

Comment: A good question. I made an edit above. Basically you can use Andy L.'s solution in your case of a simple ndarray where each row contains only one element but my edit suggests more generally how to check row equality in ndarrays

Answer (score 0):

`a.count([-1.]) / len(a)`

Note to be careful with float equality in general though

Answer (score 0):

As you say `a` is  numpy.ndarray, simply check on `-1` and use `mean` to get your desired output

```
a = np.array([[1.], [-1.], [1.]])

In [1144]: (a == -1).mean()
Out[1144]: 0.3333333333333333

In [1146]: a = np.array([[1.], [-1.], [1.], [-1.]])

In [1147]: (a == -1).mean()
Out[1147]: 0.5
```